# Enumerate all objects in a C# class

Tags: c#, class, object, enumeration

In my unit tests, I added a class with some preset objects which I can access for specific tests.

Example:
Accessing a preset

```
// try saving generic fully linked node
CategoryNode node = GenericPresetNodes.FullyLinkedTestnode;
filemanager.Save(node);
```

Some example presets

```
internal class GenericPresetNodes
{
    public static readonly CategoryNode FullyLinkedTestnode = new CategoryNode()
    {
        Name = "FullyLinkedTestnode",
        Description = "this is a fully linked\n testnode",
        ParentNodes = new string[] { "parent 0", "parent 1", "parent 2" },
        ChildNodes = new string[] { "child 0", "child 1", "child 2" }
    };
    public static readonly CategoryNode OrphanedTestnode = new CategoryNode()
    {
        Name = "OrphanedTestnode",
        Description = "this is a orphaned\n testnode",
        ParentNodes = new string[] { },
        ChildNodes = new string[] { "child 0", "child 1", "child 2" }
    };
    public static readonly CategoryNode NullParentsTestnode = new CategoryNode()
    {
        Name = "NullParentsTestnode",
        Description = "this is a NullParents\n testnode",
        ParentNodes = null,
        ChildNodes = new string[] { "child 0", "child 1", "child 2" }
    };
    public static readonly CategoryNode EmptySpaceTestnode = new CategoryNode()
    {
        Name = "EmptySpaceTestnode",
        Description = "this is a testnode \n in empty space",
        ParentNodes = null,
        ChildNodes = null
    };
}
```

I would also like to be able to work with those nodes similar to the following pseudo code:

```
CategoryNode[] samples = Type.GetType(GenericPresetNodes.CategoryNode).GetProperties();
foreach (CategoryNode node in samples)
{
    // do something
}
```

I thought about putting the `Generic Preset Nodes` into an Array or into a List but then it's not convenient to access specific samples such as `GenericPresetNodes.FullyLinkedTestnode`.

```
internal class GenericPresetNodes
{
    CategoryNode[] Samples = new CategoryNode[]
    {
        new CategoryNode() { Name = "FullyLinkedTestnode" /*,..., content*/},
        new CategoryNode() { Name = "OrphanedTestnode" /*,..., content*/},
        new CategoryNode() { Name = "NullParentsTestnode" /*,..., content*/},
        new CategoryNode() { Name = "EmptySpaceTestnode" /*,..., content*/}
    }
}
```

Alternatively, I could have all these Presets in the Class and within the Constructor of `GenericPresetNodes` I could fill the Samples[] for Enumeration.

```
internal class GenericPresetNodes
{
    public GenericPresetNodes()
    {
        Samples = new CategoryNode[]
        {
            FullyLinkedTestnode,
            OrphanedTestnode,
            NullParentsTestnode,
            EmptySpaceTestnode
        }
    }
    public static CategoryNode[] Samples;

    public static readonly CategoryNode FullyLinkedTestnode = new CategoryNode()
    {
        Name = "FullyLinkedTestnode",
        Description = "this is a fully linked\n testnode",
        ParentNodes = new string[] { "parent 0", "parent 1", "parent 2" },
        ChildNodes = new string[] { "child 0", "child 1", "child 2" }
    };
    public static readonly CategoryNode OrphanedTestnode = new CategoryNode()
    {
        Name = "OrphanedTestnode",
        Description = "this is a orphaned\n testnode",
        ParentNodes = new string[] { },
        ChildNodes = new string[] { "child 0", "child 1", "child 2" }
    };
    public static readonly CategoryNode NullParentsTestnode = new CategoryNode()
    {
        Name = "NullParentsTestnode",
        Description = "this is a NullParents\n testnode",
        ParentNodes = null,
        ChildNodes = new string[] { "child 0", "child 1", "child 2" }
    };
    public static readonly CategoryNode EmptySpaceTestnode = new CategoryNode()
    {
        Name = "EmptySpaceTestnode",
        Description = "this is a testnode \n in empty space",
        ParentNodes = null,
        ChildNodes = null
    };
}
```

Then I have 2 Locations where I need to manage the presets, which is a little more prone to errors. Is there a better way or best practice to do something like this?

I looked at the Type.GetXXX Documentations from microsoft but that did not quite seem to be what im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use reflection, but meh. I usually do something like:

```
public static IReadonlyList<CategoryNode> AllNodes { get; }
public static CategoryNode FullyLinkedTestnode { get; }
public static CategoryNode OrphanedTestnode { get; }
// ...

static GenericPresetNodes()
{
    var allNodes = new List<CategoryNode>();
    AllNodes = allNodes;

    FullyLinkedTestnode = Add(new CategoryNode(...));
    OrphanedTestnode = Add(new CategoryNode(...));
    // ...

    CategoryNode Add(CategoryNode node)
    {
        allNodes.Add(node);
        return node;
    }
}
```

Yes you still have to repeat the names (FullyLinkedTestnode etc) in two places, but there's no chance of updating one place and forgetting to update the other.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That already seems like an improvement. I have 2 Questions to your code which I hope you can answer. The `CategoryNode Add(...){...}` looks like a mini function in a function. Is that correct? Didnt know that's possible.

Comment: question 2. How is it that the list can be added but then its readonly. do I have to lock it somehow?

Comment: It's a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions), and it's adding to `allNodes` which is a `List<CategoryNote>`, not `AllNodes` (which is the `IReadOnlyList<CategoryNode>`)

Comment: ahh tank you. learned something new again.